# KnockoutJS : How do I remove an item from a child array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

#### Issue:

I'm still learning knockoutJS, please guide me if my approach is wrong.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amitava82/wMH8J/25/

While onclick of edit, I receive the json model which is represented in the view and I want to remove certain items (child array) or actions (parent array) from the model (I removed add UI to add more Actions from the fiddle for simplicity) and then finally pass the model back to server.

Now, deleting from root level is easy. I'm stuck with deleting individual item which is  **ActionParamaters** in **ActionItems** array.

#### Question:

How do I remove an item from a child array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass the clicked actionItem and the containing action array to deleteActionItem function as follows:

```
<!-- /ko -->
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bind="click: $root.deleteActionItem.bind($data, $parent)">remove item</a>
```

In your model you need to make every actionItem array observable using ko.mapping plugin (see edit function)

```
var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.data = ko.observable();

    self.edit = function() {
       self.data ( ko.mapping.fromJS(editData) );
    }
    self.log = function() {
        console.log(self.data())
    }
    self.deleteAction = function(data) {
       //delete root node
       self.data().remove(data)
    }
    self.deleteActionItem = function(data,actionItem) {
        //delete items
        data.ActionItems.remove(actionItem);
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to remove the item from array in the deleteActionItem function and since the array is observable now, the result will reflect to binded dom element.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about the bind method. I was wondering how to pass param with function call on click event until now.

Comment: it helped me greatly! however, i was not noticing the 'bind' in  .bind($data,$parent) :(! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Sam, your fiddle data was too complicated. When asking questions, you will improve your chance of getting help if you distill your fiddle down to the relevant elements. I have cooked up a [simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EenCp/1/) that illustrates nested arrays, and removal.

Here is the HTML, note that the remove function is inside the context of the array, so it calls a function on `$parent` instead of `$root`. This lets us target the context directly above, instead of the root.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: editData">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <button data-bind="click: $parent.removeParent">Remove Parent</button>
        ...
            <!-- This line is on the child context -->
            <button data-bind="click: $parent.removeChild">Remove Child</button>

</ul>​
```

Here is the parent model. Note the removal function here is for removing children. When the `removeChild` function is called, it is from the child context asking for `$parent`, which will call this remove.

```
var Parent = function(name, children) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.children = ko.observableArray(children);
    self.removeChild = function(child) {
        self.children.remove(child);
    };
};
```

Your fiddle also makes no use of models, which are an important aspect of MVVM development. You should consider going through [the tutorials on the knockout site](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) to get a better understanding of how to structure knockout applications. It will help you deal with problems like this much easier.

Comment: Thank you Tyrsius for the detailed explanation. I'm still learning KO (did the tutorial first). I'm still looking for some good resources that demonstrate KO with complex data and UI (not just simple shopping cart). In your example, you used arraymap to map the data into model. For complex data like mine, how difficult is it to do? I'm using mapping plugin to map all the properties since my data is very complex.

Comment: I find the mapping plugin to be more trouble than its worth, honestly. `arrayMap` is simple, and client-side models need to be written for any complex model anyway, since most will need methods. I have written sufficiently complex models without much trouble, but it takes a different kind of thinking than you might be used to. The KO tutorials will prepare you for this kind of development, even if they are simple. I highly recommend them.

Comment: Hi @Tyrsius. Can you please solve my issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54320140/knockout-remove-array-element-by-specific-field-value