# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0

I am trying to use knockout.js with MVC3 and I keep on getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined

The set up is that I have a UL List that I need to add to and remove from:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: Interviewees">
   <li>
       <div>
           <a data-bind="click: $root.removeInterviewee" class="xOut"></a>
        </div>
       <div>
          <h2>
              <span data-bind="text: FirstName"></span>
               <span data-bind="text: LastName"></span>
          </h2>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the javascript section that has the knockout stuff:

```
function SomeThingee(Id, SomeThingeeId, firstName, lastName, title, email) {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.SomeThingeeId = SomeThingeeId;
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
        this.Title = title;
        this.Email = email;
    }

    var viewModel = ko.validatedObservable({
        addSomeThingee: function () {
            if (!viewModel.isValid()) {
                viewModel.errors.showAllMessages();
                return false;
            } else {
                var newSomeThingee = new SomeThingee(this.Id(), 0, this.FirstName(), this.LastName(), this.Title(), this.Email());

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("AddSomeThingee")',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: ko.toJSON(newSomeThingee),
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (result) {
                        newSomeThingee.SomeThingeeId = result.message; 
                    },
                    error: function (result) {

                    }
                });

                    this.SomeThingees.push(newSomeThingee);
                }
        },
        removeSomeThingee: function (item) {
            this.SomeThingees.remove(item);
        }
    });

    $(function () {
        var jsonModel = '@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model))';
        var mvcModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonModel);

        var myViewModel = new viewModel();
        var g = ko.mapping.fromJS(myViewModel, mvcModel);

        ko.applyBindings(g, document.getElementById("someDiv"));

    });
```

Error occurs at this line:

```
this.SomeThingees.remove(item);
```

Note the SomeThingees collection is supplied from the Model itself. The add method works perfectly fine, but the remove method doesn't work and give me the error listed above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The correct answer can be found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398647/knockoutjs-how-do-i-remove-an-item-from-a-child-array

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that when the `click` binding calls `$root.removeInterviewee`, `this` is set to the data-item (`$data`) instead of the view-model (`$root`). There are a few ways to work around this. Probably the easiest is to use `bind` on the function reference in your binding.

```
<a data-bind="click: $root.removeInterviewee.bind($root)" class="xOut"></a>
```

Also see this [Github issue](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/378) for further discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the problem was with the binding calls set to the data-item ($data) instead of the view-model ($root). I've changed `<button data-bind="click: $root.(your delete function).bind($root)"></button>` and worked for me! thanks Michael Best