# Knockout : Remove array element by specific field value

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to remove ko observable array element by specific field value. I tried one solution. But, there are something missing. It's not working.

```
customOptionVal : ko.observableArray([])
```

customOptionVal is ko observableArray and output of that is :

```
Color: [0: {sub_color: "Red", sub_id: "options_3_2", is_checked: true}
1: {sub_color: "Green + $250.00", sub_id: "options_3_3", is_checked: true}]
Size: {sub_size: "L", sub_id: "options_2_2", is_checked: true}
```

Now, I want like that if **sub_id = options_3_2** then, it will remove from **Color element** on the base of **sub_id**.

I tried this below solution. But, it's not working :

```
$.each(self.customOptionVal()['Color'], function( key, val ) {
                    if(self.customOptionVal()['Color'][key].sub_id == 'options_3_2') {
                        self.customOptionVal.remove(self.customOptionVal()['Color'][key]);
                    }
                });
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to remove the Color element or the Option that has that color element altogether? I ask this because you are removing from the observable array `self.customOptionVal`

Comment: It's not working for me.

Comment: How are you able to access `self.customOptionVal()['Color']` if `customOptionVal ` is an `observableArray`? I'm assuming you're setting an object with keys `Color` and `Size` to `ko.observableArray()`. It should be changed to a `ko.observable()`

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet removes from the `customOptionVal observableArray` itself -

```
self.customOptionVal.remove(function(option) {
  return ko.utils.arrayFilter(option.Color, function(color) {
    return color.sub_id === subId;
  });
});
```

However, if you only want to remove from the `Color` array (which is not an `observableArray`), use the following snippet -

```
self.customOptionVal().forEach(function(option) {
  var index = option["Color"].findIndex(function(y) {
    return y.sub_id === subId;
  });

  if (index > -1) {
    option["Color"].splice(index, 1);
  }

});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/knjxb4go/)

Comment: Can you please tell me other way ? ko.utils.arrayForEach is not working,

Comment: Is it possible to do some modification in my code and get output?

Comment: I don't see any reason why `ko.utils.arrayForEach` didn't work for you...I have updated the solution though..now it uses vanilla js instead of knockout for iteration...Fiddle is updated as well

Comment: Still, it's not working. I added image. I'm doing in Magento. This console is about self.customOptionVal(). You can see that there are custom_option_id in Color. I want to remove on the base of custom_option_id. On click, I can get value of custom_option_id.

Comment: How can i get 0 index all value. I used self.customOptionVal()['Color'][0] . But, it's not working.

Comment: Since `self.customOptionVal` is an `observableArray`, `self.customOptionVal()` will return an `array`..and so you can't get the property name `Color` from an `array` when you do this `self.customOptionVal()['Color'][0]`...You can try doing this `self.customOptionVal().map(function(x) { return x.Color; })[0]` if you want values related to the first element in the `Color` array. Try this out to see what I mean by map  `self.customOptionVal()[0]['Color'][0]`

Answer (score 0):

I found better way that :

As see in screenshot, create one ko observable array and set **Color** value in that **ko.observableArray**

```
custom_option_select_text_arr = ko.observableArray([])
.....
this.custom_option_select_text_arr.push({sub_color: "Red", sub_id: "options_3_2", is_checked: true});
this.customOptionVal()['Color'] = this.custom_option_select_text_arr();
```

Now, for remove element :

```
self.custom_option_select_text_arr.remove(self.custom_option_select_text_arr()[0]);
self.customOptionVal()['Color'] = this.custom_option_select_text_arr();
```